# php codeigniter mail function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

i wa trying to do mail with php codeigner, but unfortunately its not working. the error which i got was the following; somebody please help me..

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to localhost:8025 (Connection refused)

Filename: libraries/smtp.php

Line Number: 105

Thanks in advance

Ahamed

Comment: Have you set anything in the $config of the email class like described here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html ?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are trying to connect to port 8025, and this fails. The default smtp port is 25, so either you used the wrong port number or there is no mail service running on port 8025 on localhost, but whatever the cause this is something you should probably change in your configuration somewhere.

Another option is to change the mail protocol from smtp to native php mail, refer to the [CodeIgniter docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) on how to do this (and make sure you set this up correctly - especially if you are using Windows, check php.ini).